# What are the visas that allow a company to employ a student that is about to graduate?

Tags: usa, working-visas

I am not a US citizen and I am  studying and planning to get my master's degree by the end of the year. 
During the past 3 months I have been an intern in a US company using the Academic Training program granted by my J1 visa. The J1 was sponsored by a US university where I studied one semester. The company is very happy with my results and they would like to keep me.

As far as I know the H1b visa is the best option to be allowed to come back to the US and keep working for them. They are willing to sponsor me but I know that the H1b visa is very hard to get. What would be other options for the company to have me come back?

For example, would it be possible for them to issue me an internship J1 visa while waiting to apply me for H1b?

Comment: Sorry, we don't handle questions about student and work visas. See our sister site [expatriates.se].